# De-Serialize object to memory

Tags: java, deserialization

I am running my indexing program in Java to index a huge data set into a Tree Data structure. I then serialize it to save it in disk. My Search program would then De-serialize the object and performs a search for each given input on the index.

But i notice that each time De-serializing the object and performing the search has overhead and slows my search.
I wanted to understand what would be a good way to De-serialize an object and keep it in memory instead of De-serializing each time using Java?

Regards,
Nish.

Comment: When you say "each time" do you mean stopping, and starting the application? If so, then you can't keep it in memory because the memory is gone when the application exits. If the program is running the whole time, just don't write it to disk and instead keep a reference to the Tree in your application.

Comment: Your question is still lacking some context

Comment: The program is to lookup the nearest points out of a set of points to the input point. I was thinking since the program has a main() method each time it is called to search a nearest point it finds and returns  the result and exits the program.and so the index loaded to memory needs to be generated again or the serialized file needs to be deserialized again. I don't understand how an application keeps running the whole time. How do we achieve that?

Comment: @nishanth, see update to my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you using lasy-loading?

```
Index indexCache = null;

synchronized Index getIndex() {
    if (indexCache == null)
        indexCache = deserializeIndex();

    return indexCache;
}

Index deserializeIndex() {
    File indexFile = new File(indexFilePath());

    ....
}

List<Result> searchInIndex(Query query) {
    Index index = getIndex();

    List<Result> results = index.fetch(query);

    ....
}
```

**Upd.**

If your's program is serving as some service provider im the middle of chain - consider to rewrite it into client/server service:

Server:

- Your's server starts, reads and de-serializes index from harddrive.
- Then it creates socket (or named pipe?) and listens to connections on certain port.
- When client connects to port, server reads request from it, processes it and sends search results back.

Client:

- When client starts, it takes provided input (from user? from console?).
- Then it connects to server on known port.
- Sends input to server, receives response.
- Gives response to user/terminal/whatever.
- Terminates.

*Note: Overhead of networking on local machine is a matter of microseconds. So, client/server approach is more efficient if overhead of re-reading/de-serializing is bigger than that.*

Comment: Thank you for the reply @ankhzet. I will explore the Client/server service option further and rewrite my code. As you mentioned i feel that should be the right way to do it.